# Plotting a time-ordered sequence of boolean values in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using R.

Suppose I have a time ordered sequence of boolean values: either W or L.

How can I get to something similar to the plot below with ggplot2?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I kind of got something to work using a combination of `geom_rect` for the shapes, `geom_text` for the labels, and `geom_bracket` (from `ggpubr`) for the labels above or below the axis.  The general idea is to plot rectangles or other shapes along the axis.  You can potentially use `geom_label` to create the boxes, but it's harder to set the width constant, especially if your labels are different lengths.

```
# Data set for W/L record.  Time is arbitrary
set.seed(12345)
df <- data.frame(
  time=1:10,
  result=sample(c('W','L'),10,replace=TRUE)
)

# data set for labels
bracket.labels <- data.frame(
  x.from=c(1, 2, 5, 6),
  x.to=c(3, 5, 7, 10),
  lab=c('Weak', 'Had a problem', 'Good times', 'End of year')
)

# the plot
library(ggpubr)

ggplot(df, aes(x=time)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept=0) +
  geom_rect(aes(fill=result, xmin=time-0.4, xmax=time+0.4),
    ymin=-0.1, ymax=0.1, show.legend = FALSE) +
  geom_text(y=0, color='white',
    aes(label=result), fontface='bold') +
  ylim(-0.5,1.5) + theme_void() +
  scale_fill_manual(name=NULL, values=c('brown1', 'forestgreen')) +
  geom_bracket(data=bracket.labels, y.position=0.2,
    aes(xmin=x.from, xmax=x.to, label=lab),
    step.increase = 1, tip.length = 0.3)
```

[image]

There's probably other solutions you could use, since this is one of those questions that demands some creativity in the response.  Other methods may involve use of `geom_tile` (I tried, but didn't like it) or create the whole thing via custom annotations.